# Lifetime of Customer Payment Data in Authorize.net

Tags: payment, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am trying to connect Authorize.net payment to the website.
My goal is to create a crowdfunding function for the website. 
And I can't found a description where Authorize.net says how long it keeps Customer Payment Information, which I save through the Authorize API and getHostedProfilePageRequest method.

How long does Authorize keep Customer Payment Information?

Comment: Are you asking if a payment profile expires?

Comment: Thank you for your question. 
Yes, I was asking about that, and the support team of Authorize.net answered to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. The support team replied to me.
Here is their answer:

> CIM profiles would be saved around 2 years after the card expires. As
>   the card can no longer be used after it expires, it's worth deleting
>   the information since it's no longer valid.